# How to get liferay remote user from Filter class

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I want to access liferay remote user ID from filter class.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
                     ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest =  (HttpServletRequest) request;
        User user = (User)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.USER);

        System.out.println("User ID :" + user.getUserId());
        System.out.println("User ID :" + httpServletRequest.getRemoteUser());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output

```
User :null
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please tell me how can I get remote user ID form `HttpServletRequest`?

Comment: You have a strange way of indenting code mate. Not sure if you had the edit privilige yet, but it's concidered good practice to check your post formatting and language even after posting. Like here the mixed tabs and spaces you used for formatting caused the code to look very hard to read. I edited it bit for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getUser(HttpServletRequest request)` to get the Liferay User.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
            ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;   
        User user = PortalUtil.getUser(request);    
        System.out.println("User ID :" + user.getUserId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you have any hints as to why would `PortalUtil.getUser()` return null? The user is logged in according to Liferay - /c/portal/login counts the user as logged in anyway, but in doFilter I get null for the user.

Comment: Sorry, I don't recall having a similar problem, and it would be hard for me to take a look at this, as I'm not working with Liferay anymore. Should be worth debugging your app, and inspect your `request` and `httpServletRequest` objects. It could also be a session timeout? Maybe you should create a new question, as the Liferay version could be a factor here.